# Multiple buttons and multiple modals of the same class, show one modal when clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to make a modal appear when a button is clicked, I have multiple buttons and modals of the same class. I wrote a small jQuery code, but when I click any button all modals appear at once. I need somehow to make appear only the corresponding modal when the corresponding button is clicked. But once again, I have the same classes for all the buttons and modals.

I wrote a simplified demo, so that it was more clear:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $( ".modal" ).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  margin: 30px;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.95);
    color: #fff;
    width: 12vw;
    height: 80px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>open modal</button>
  <div class="modal">modal</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>open modal</button>
  <div class="modal">modal</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button>open modal</button>
  <div class="modal">modal</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$(".modal") selector select all modal and added active class to it so you have to make change like I have made

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $( "."+e.target.id).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  margin: 30px;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.95);
    color: #fff;
    width: 12vw;
    height: 80px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="button1">open modal</button>
  <div class="button1 modal">modal</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button id="button2">open modal</button>
  <div class="button2 modal">modal</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button id="button3">open modal</button>
  <div class="button3 modal">modal</div>
</div>
```